# Output without new line

Tags: python, newline

how can I output text to the console without new line at the end?
for example:

```
print 'temp1'
print 'temp2'
```

output:

```
temp1 
temp2
```

And I need:

```
temp1temp2
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

<strike>Add a comma after the last argument:</strike>

```
print 'temp1',
print 'temp2'
```

Alternatively, Call `sys.stdout.write`:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("Some output")
```

Comment: The comma will still introduce a space between the strings.

Answer (score 28):

In Python > 2.6 and Python 3:

```
from __future__ import print_function

print('temp1', end='')
print('temp2', end='')
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
print 'temp1',
print 'temp2'
```

Comment: The comma will still introduce a space between the strings.

Comment: Note that this will still add a space between test1 and test2, which is not what the OP said he needed.

Comment: Add a .replace(" ","") after the first bit.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways, but the usual choice is to use `sys.stdout.write()`, which -- unlike `print` -- prints exactly what you want. In Python 3.x (or in Python 2.6 with `from __future__ import print_function`) you can also use `print(s, end='', sep='')`, but at that point `sys.stdout.write()` is probably easier.

Another way would be to build a single string and print that:

```
>>> print "%s%s" % ('temp1', 'temp2')
```

But that obviously requires you to wait with writing until you know both strings, which is not always desirable, and it means having the entire string in memory (which, for big strings, may be an issue.)

Comment: sys.stdout.write() also seems to append the number of characters to the output. sys.stdout.write("test") prints test4. Why is it doing this, and how do I make it stop?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(4): 

    print(a[i], end =" ")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
print 'temp1',
print '\btemp2'
```